# Can't use pip3 modules: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I leveraged homebrew to install python3 and now I cannot run modules I install with the associated pip3 binary.

```
from blackduck.HubRestApi import HubInstance
username = "sysadmin"
password = "your-password"
urlbase = "https://ec2-34-201-23-208.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
hub = HubInstance(urlbase, username, password, insecure=True)
```

Running `python3 blackduck.py` Results in :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blackduck.HubRestApi'; 'blackduck' is not a package
```

Proof of package:

```
$pip3 install blackduck                                                                                                                                    
Requirement already satisfied: blackduck in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.25)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from blackduck) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->blackduck) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->blackduck) (2019.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->blackduck) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->blackduck) (3.0.4)
```

`help('modules')` -> contains `blackduck`

```
$pip3 list | grep blackduck          
blackduck  0.0.25
```

I've tried to create a virtual environment, to no avail. I also tried adding `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` to my `$PYTHONPATH` env variable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't call your own python script the same as a python module or package - it picks *itself* up!!!!  Call it anything else, like `my_blackduck.py`.

Comment: @cdarke You saved my day. If you post this as a proposed solution I will select it as the accepted answer!

Comment: You're welcome, and there is probably a duplicate if only I could find it.  You are not the first to do that and you won't be the last.  Solution posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call your own python script the same as a python module or package - it picks itself up!

From [the search-path documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
> for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
> for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
> variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> The directory containing the input script (or the current directory
> when no file is specified).
>
> PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
>
> The installation-dependent default.

So, all things being equal, the current directory is searched first.

Call it anything else, like `my_blackduck.py`.  I recommend you use a homegrown prefix, maybe a project-code followed by something like an underscore, for development scripts so that you don't repeat the problem.